# Is portability something to worry about when implementing basic binary serialization for a video game?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, serialization

I am writing a simple binary serializer to generate save files for a 64-bit video game targeting Windows, Mac and Linux 64-bit platforms. The variable types selected for serialisation are: char, short, bool, unsigned int, int, float, possibly double and possibly long int. I am compiling on Visual Studio. The serialisation is as simple as possible, with no checks, just simple writing of the binary data and then deserialization of the data in the same order. The game saves new data to the file very frequently throughout play, but the data is deserialized only once, just before play.

I didn’t think that portability was something that I needed to worry about with a simple save-game function; however, I have been reading about the many portability problems associated with binary serialisation (e.g. floating-point representation, variations in the bitwidth of ints, endianness, alignment etc.) and I am not confident enough in my understanding of the subject to be certain that these portability problems won’t rear their head with this project. Perhaps someone would be so kind as to share some perspective on the following assumptions:

1. The variables may be serialised to a binary on one machine and the
   binary may then be copied over and safely deserialized on a
   different machine with the same OS and an x86-64 CPU.
2. If I assume that all the machines running the game are little-endian x86-64 style CPUs running 64-bit operating systems,
   can I assume that the binary file can be fully portable between
   operating systems too?
3. If I were to expand development to support a 32-bit version of the game (still assuming an x86-64 CPU architecture on the target
   platform, but 32-bit OS), and a 32-bit OS end user decides to
   upgrade to a 64-bit OS, installs the 64-bit version of the game and
   then loads up their old save file which was serialised on the 32-bit
   OS running the 32-bit version of the game—can those variable types
   then be safely deserialized on the 64-bit platform in the order in
   which they were serialised without any checks or tests for
   compatibility?

Is it possible that saving on one machine and loading on another could corrupt the data in any of these scenarios?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only plan to support x86 endian shouldn't be a concern. The variability of integer sizes can be worked around with the fixed width integers defined in `cstdint`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sized integer types such as `::std::uint32_t` instead of obscure types such as `unsigned long` then you will be pretty much save from integer size variations that may occur between 32-bit/64-bit platforms and different compilers. Integer bitwidth technically may vary, but only on rather exotic platforms that definitely can not be considered suitable for gaming. Floating point size and representation should not be a concern either.

To make sure that size and alignment of data structures being read / written remains consistent across platforms you should use `static_assert` in you code.

However checking endianness is mandatory if you want your save files to be portable. Typically you may want to serialize data using native endianness and write some magic number in the beginning of the file indicating its endianness (like `0x01020304`). Then when you deserialize you first check this magic and select either native endianness deserializer (which is faster) or flipped endianness deserializer (which is slower).

Comment: Many thanks, that's close to what I had planned. Is converting endian types during deserialization as simple as reversing the byte order; i.e. I don't need to worry about reordering individual bits?

Comment: Yes, reordering bits is not necessary.